# VM resolution no better in VirtualBox despite installing Guest Edition

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7

Installed the guest edition in **CentOS7** vdi and rebooted the system and then went out of scaled mode. but the resolution still doesn't look good .

Its confined to **1024 X 768** and scroll bars appear along the window borders.

**NOTE :** I am using Windows 10 Enterprise Edition.

Can someone guide me here.i have done this previously and it worked fine but the earlier system was host system Windows Home edition.

Answer (score 2):

You have maybe installed the guest additions from the VirtualBox menu.

If that's the case, try to uninstall that version of guest additions
and install it instead from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```